# Converting array to objects within an object

Tags: json, jq

I have been battling with this for sometime, ive looked a few articles in regards to this topic. I can't seem to get exactly what I'm aiming for. I have this original json data that I would like to transform a bit.

Group the objects based on the label.env (for now only using one env), then inserting those objects  from the original json into an object named projects.

orginial_json

```
{
  "createTime": "2020-06-25T14:16:45.720Z",
  "labels": {
    "cb_domain": "cloud-services",
    "cb_product": "infra",
    "env": "prod",
    "owner": "cloud-server"
  },
  "lifecycleState": "ACTIVE",
  "name": "projectname",
  "parent": {
    "id": "123456577",
    "type": "folder"
  },
  "projectId": "projectname-324234",
  "projectNumber": "962363417856"
}
{
  "createTime": "2020-06-24T19:45:42.851Z",
  "labels": {
    "cb_domain": "cloud-services",
    "cb_product": "ad",
    "env": "prod",
    "owner": "cloud-server"
  },
  "lifecycleState": "ACTIVE",
  "name": "projectname2",
  "parent": {
    "id": "4352564765437",
    "type": "folder"
  },
  "projectId": "projectname2-4567",
  "projectNumber": "3243456324"
}
```

Im using `jq -s 'group_by(.labels.env) | .[] | { (.[0].labels.env) : { projects: .[] | . } }'`
to nest the original json data into objects grouped by env\projects, which works but seems to duplicate it instead of putting each object within projects.

```
{
  "prod": {
    "projects": {
      "createTime": "2020-06-25T14:16:45.720Z",
      "labels": {
        "cb_domain": "cloud-services",
        "cb_product": "infra",
        "env": "prod",
        "owner": "cloud-server"
      },
      "lifecycleState": "ACTIVE",
      "name": "projectname",
      "parent": {
        "id": "770593713153",
        "type": "folder"
      },
      "projectId": "projectname-324234",
      "projectNumber": "962363417856"
    }
  }
}
{
  "prod": {
    "projects": {
      "createTime": "2020-06-24T19:45:42.851Z",
      "labels": {
        "cb_domain": "cloud-services",
        "cb_product": "ad",
        "env": "prod",
        "owner": "cloud-server"
      },
      "lifecycleState": "ACTIVE",
      "name": "projectname2",
      "parent": {
        "id": "4352564765437",
        "type": "folder"
      },
      "projectId": "projectname2-4567",
      "projectNumber": "3243456324"
    }
  }
}
```

What I'm aiming for is

```
{
  "prod": {
    "projects": {
      "createTime": "2020-06-25T14:16:45.720Z",
      "labels": {
        "cb_domain": "cloud-services",
        "cb_product": "infra",
        "env": "prod",
        "owner": "cloud-server"
      },
      "lifecycleState": "ACTIVE",
      "name": "projectname",
      "parent": {
        "id": "770593713153",
        "type": "folder"
      },
      "projectId": "projectname-324234",
      "projectNumber": "962363417856"
    },
    {
      "createTime": "2020-06-24T19:45:42.851Z",
      "labels": {
        "cb_domain": "cloud-services",
        "cb_product": "ad",
        "env": "prod",
        "owner": "cloud-server"
      },
      "lifecycleState": "ACTIVE",
      "name": "projectname2",
      "parent": {
        "id": "4352564765437",
        "type": "folder"
      },
      "projectId": "projectname2-4567",
      "projectNumber": "3243456324"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `jq` is not `jQuery`.  Please read the details of that tag for more information.

Comment: What you're aiming for is not a valid json ...

Comment: @Selim is correct about the posted desired output. Murda - please fix so the Q can be upvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allowing for some minor discrepancies in the Q, the following variant of your jq program seems to do what you're trying to achieve:

```
group_by(.labels.env)
| .[]
| .[0].labels.env as $key
| { ($key) : { projects: . } }
```

Comment: Thanks this works, I had also came up with this that works as well. `group_by(.labels.env) | .[] | { (.[0].labels.env) : { projects: map( {(.name|tostring): . } ) | add } }`